# Owl carousel is not rendering after page transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, owl-carousel

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.transitions.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div><h1>1</h1></div>
<div><h1>2</h1></div>
<div><h1>3</h1></div>
<div><h1>4</h1></div>
<div><h1>5</h1></div>
<div><h1>6</h1></div>
</div>
<script>

var owl = $("#owl-demo");

owl.owlCarousel({
 itemsCustom : [
                   [0, 5],
                   [450, 5],
                   [600, 5],
                   [700, 5],
                   [1000, 5]
                   ],
                   scrollPerPage : true
});


</script>
```

The first time the carousel is loading and rendering properly. The problem I am facing is that on transition of the pages in Cordova Project, it is not loading/rendering in corresponding pages.

Comment: Have you debugged it? Try adding some `console.log('got here');` outside the `owl.owlCarousel`, checking if javascript is re-running in every page. Try even using the owl [callback engine](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html) and use the `console.log()` there. Even try using `console.log($("#owl-demo"))` to be sure that your element is present where it is supposed to be.

Comment: I suspect that your problem is that javascript isn't re-running in every page transition. If so, you need to add the code INTO the "page transition" [callback engine](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#endcallbutton).

Comment: i am using this plugin for mobiles. At first plugin css is working properly when i'm making the transitions,plugin css and html is not appending on that transition pages.